# Serialize struct to byte array with pointer as struct member

Tags: c

I am trying to copy a byte array to my struct, then serialize my struct to a byte array again.

But, after I serialize my struct array, I cant get my data value (0x12, 0x34, 0x56) again, instead i get some rubbish data.

What is wrong here?

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct {
    uint8_t length;
    uint8_t *data;
} Tx_Packet;
#pragma pack(pop)

static void create_tx_packet(uint8_t *packet, uint8_t *src, int length);

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t packet[32];
    uint8_t data[] = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56 };

    create_tx_packet(packet, data, 3);

    //i check using debugger, i cant get the data value correctly
    //but i could get length value correctly


    return 0;
}

static void create_tx_packet(uint8_t *packet, uint8_t *src, int length)
{
    Tx_Packet *tx_packet = malloc(sizeof(*tx_packet ));

    tx_packet->length = length;
    tx_packet->data = (uint8_t *)malloc(length);
    memcpy(tx_packet->data, src, length);

    memcpy(packet, tx_packet, sizeof(*tx_packet));
}
```

Comment: to compile, the following headers are needed: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, your `create_tx_packet()` function copies a `Tx_Packet` struct created in the function to a `uint8_t` array.  That struct contains the length and a *pointer* to the data, but not the data itself.  It's actually not necessary to use the struct as an intermediate step at all, particularly for such a simple packet, so you could instead do:

```
static void create_tx_packet(uint8_t *packet, uint8_t *src, int length)
{
  *packet = length; /* set (first) uint8_t pointed to by packet to the
                       length */
  memcpy(packet + 1, src, length);  /* copy length bytes from src to
                                       the 2nd and subsequent bytes of
                                       packet */
}
```

You still need to make sure `packet` points to enough space (at least `length + 1` bytes) for everything (which it does).  Since the version above doesn't dynamically allocate anything, it also fixes the memory leaks in your original (which should have freed `tx_packet->data` and `tx_packet` before exiting).

--

If you do want to use a struct, you can (since the data is at the end) change your struct to use an array instead of a pointer for `data` -- then extra space past the size of the struct can be used for the data, and accessed through the `data` array in the struct.  The struct might be:

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t length;
  uint8_t data[];
} Tx_Packet;
```

and the function becomes (if a temporary struct is used):

```
static void create_tx_packet(uint8_t *packet, uint8_t *src, int length)
{
  /* allocate the temporary struct, with extra space at the end for the
     data */
  Tx_Packet *tx_packet = malloc(sizeof(Tx_Packet)+length);

  /* fill the struct (set length, copy data from src) */
  tx_packet->length = length;
  memcpy(tx_packet->data, src, length);

  /* copy the struct and following data to the output array */
  memcpy(packet, tx_packet, sizeof(Tx_Packet) + length);

  /* and remember to free our temporary struct/data */
  free(tx_packet);
}
```

Rather than allocate a temporary struct, though, you could also use struct pointer to access the byte array in `packet` directly and avoid the extra memory allocation:

```
static void create_tx_packet(uint8_t *packet, uint8_t *src, int length)
{
  /* Set a Tx_Packet pointer to point at the output array */
  Tx_Packet *tx_packet = (Tx_Packet *)packet;

  /* Fill out the struct as before, but this time directly into the
     output array so we don't need to allocate and copy so much */
  tx_packet->length = length;
  memcpy(tx_packet->data, src, length);
}
```

Comment: that is a good solution! thank you! :), but that is just a simplify version, but if i do want to fix that problem, what should i do?

Comment: You could change your struct to use an array at the end instead of a pointer, and allocate extra space for the data when you allocate the struct.

Comment: yup that what i thought, but then i wanted to use pointer cuz is more efficient (dynamically allocate the memory) but i found this problem, so if i would like to stick using pointer the solution would be?

Comment: @Tim Allocate the entire struct dynamically and add the size of your array to the allocation.

Comment: thank you! i love the last solution, is very neat and clean! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `memcpy(packet, tx_packet, sizeof(*tx_packet));` you are copying the memory representation of `tx_Packet` into packet, starting with `tx_packet->length`.

Additionally when mallocating tx_packet that size should be `sizeof(*packet)+sizeof(uint8_t)` (length of packet plus length field)

And again when copying the `tx_packet` back to `packet` you are writing out of the boundaries of `packet`.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that depending on your compiler memory alignment parameter you could get any length for the fields (including `tx_packet->length`) to accelerate memory operation.  On 32bits machine it could be 4 and padded with rubbish.

Comment: thanks for the info, i am using 32 bits, and i have set pragma to remove the padding. but i still dont know how can i store my data in my struct

Answer (score 0):

When you serialize your struct with

```
memcpy(packet, tx_packet, sizeof(*tx_packet));
```

you're copying the length and the pointer to the data, but not the data itself.  You'll probably need two `memcpy` calls: one of `sizeof(uint8_t)` to copy the length field, and one of `length` to copy the data.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
Tx_Packet *tx_packet = malloc(sizeof(*packet));
```

only allocates one byte for the packet header, which you then immediately write off the end of, causing undefined behavior.  You probably meant

```
Tx_Packet *tx_packet = malloc(sizeof(*tx_packet));
```

Comment: sorry it is a typo there, i have change it